# Coefficient of an expansion

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

Find the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(x+a)(x+b)...(x+n)$ where $a$, $b$ and $n$ are integers.

I am not able to approach this problem.

Comment: I see no pattern in the expression $(x+a)(x+b)\cdots(x+n)$. Are you interested in expanding the rising factorial $$(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x+k)$$ or the product of arbitrary linear factors $$(x+a_1)(x+a_2)\cdots(x+a_n)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x+a_k)$$ ?

Comment: arbitrary linear factors

Comment: It is the [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) $e_k(a,b, \ldots, n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the polynomial will result in:

$$(x+a)(x+b)...(x+n)=x^n + (a + b + ... + n)x^{n-1} + (ab + ac + ... + an + ... + bn + ...)x^{n-2} + ...$$

So the coefficient of $x^k$ will simply be $$\sum_{a_1, a_2, ... a_{n-k}} a_1 a_2 ... a_{n-k},$$

where $a_1, a_2, ..., a_{n-k} \in {a, b, ..., n}$ and $a_i \neq a_j$ for every $i \neq j$.

In other words this is called a [symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial), so what you're looking for is $e_k(a, b, ..., n)$.